# Dynamically creating custom projection visually using QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

I'm actually creating a game board, I have shapefiles for a US Map, rivers and states...would like the geography to remain somewhat realistic, but I need to some how do some squashing and stretching and I was wondering if there was a way to dynamically do something where I can see what's going on?  I can always do something in Photoshop, but would like to be able to edit this as needed later.

The area between the Lower Mississippi and TomBigbee river isn't realistically wide enough for my game spaces so trying to spread it some and have the state lines shift the same.

[image]

Comment: You could draw your own, generalized rivers.

Comment: As I mentioned I could do it myself in some ways, my hope was to warp the state lines with the river in the same way.

Comment: What do you mean by wrap the state lines? Planning to change the boundary of the states according to the stretch of the river???

Answer (score 2):

Try transforming the data (each layer with the same parameters) with the ["Affine transform"](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#affine-transform) tool with a `scaling factor` on the `x-axis` more than 1 and move all the elements back to their original positions manually in edit mode. You may have to pick up the desired scaling factor manually.

Here is the result of the transformation with the `x-axis scaling factor` = 0.8

[image: Scale factor=0.8]